# How to get network to "see" 14.04 desktop?

Tags: networking, samba

I'm also having problems with a new install of 14.04 desktop. I'm a novice to Ubuntu.
I have another pc running 14.04 Studio and it works fine with my windows network.

I did the following:

```
[quote="ronnbot, post:8, topic:1301"]
```

Started fresh by removing samba:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove samba samba-common
sudo apt-get autoremove system-config-samba
```

Reinstall samba:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
sudo apt-get install system-config-samba cifs-utils
```

I copied smb.conf.default (thanks cariboo​907 for the link) into `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

**I could not save the smb.conf file as I get a red banner stating that I don't have permission to change a read only file. In both the /usr/share/samba, and /etc/samba**

Then I launched the samba app to set my samba user but this will not work in Unity Dash (it does not show the application "samba" and the samba configuration tool does not open).

I also could not get all the files. I read in another forum that you could do the following:

First, check your machine is fully updated. Open command line (Ctrl + Alt + F1): or in my case (Ctrl + Alt +T)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you get any errors, run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then rerun to first two commands to ensure no further errors. After that you can try logging in (Ctrl-Alt-F7 to change to you GUI) to see if Unity is now working.

If Unity is still not running, follow these instructions to reset your unity configuration, (from How do I reset my Unity configuration?):

With 14.04 install unity-tweak-tool:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Then run the follow command to reset Unity to defaults:

```
unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
```

(In my case Unity started working after 14 files either updated or were added.
The Samba server configuration GUI started working and I can add shares.
I can "see" the network from the Ubuntu-desktop pc but the pc is not named and a "smb-server" is listed. I can see and log into shares for the Win7, Win8 and the other Ubuntu-Studio pcs. I can't "see" the Ubuntu-desktop pc from anywhere on the network!)

My configuration files reside only in (no `/var/lib/samba`), the shares, located in `/var/lib/samba/usershares`, and look similar to this:

VERSION 2

```
path=/home/Desktop/vaio
comment=
usershare_acl=S-1-1-0:F
guest_ok=y              (mine had an n which I changed to a y)
sharename=Public
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Revision to original post:

After changing different parts of the OS for about a week and continuously getting internal error messages, I decided to wipe out the OS install and start over.
I reloaded everything again and added samba but could not get Unity Dash and the GUI with the Samba server configuration to work again even though samba showed to be installed.

I surfed and finally ran across an article:

Comment: Your post seems to have both the question and solution. You might want to separate them for the sake of clarity

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Fix For Ubuntu 14.04**

Remove any samba related apps:

```
sudo apt-get remove samba samba-common
sudo apt-get remove system-config-samba
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't have `gksu` installed by default so install and configure it

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
gksu-properties
```

In the dialogue that follows set authentication mode to "sudo" and grab mode to "enable".

Install samba

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common
```

At the prompt for `smb.conf` choose to overwrite the `smb.conf` file.

```
sudo apt-get install samba system-config-samba cifs-utils`
```

After this the samba icon showed in the dock and everything works fine.

Setting Samba user password

To add yourself to the Samba user list, you just have to type the following command:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

Replace with your username. It will then prompt you to set a password for this Samba account.

Alternatively, you can also create a new user account and add this user to the Samba user list

To create a user account, use the following command:

```
sudo adduser <username>
```

Restart Samba services

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

Everything works now.